# Get rid of "if" - Boolean Logic

Tags: c, boolean, logic

I was wondering if we could get rid of all the "if" statements only by using boolean logic.

```
int main() {
    int a,b,c,d;
    char e;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    scanf("%d", &d);

    if (d == 0)
    {
        e = 'O'*((a+b == c) || (a+c == b) || (b+c == a));
        e += (e == 0)*'X';

        printf("%c\n",e);
    }

    if (d == 1)
    {
        e = 'O'*((a*b == c) || (a*c == b) || (b*c == a));
        e += (e == 0)*'X';

        printf("%c\n",e);
    }
}
```

So far I've been able to replace

```
if ((a+b == c) || (a+c == b) || (b+c == a))
{
e = '0';
}

else
{
e = 'X';
}
```

by

```
e = 'O'*((a+b == c) || (a+c == b) || (b+c == a));
e += (e == 0)*'X';
```

is there any way to get rid of the lines

```
if (d == 0)
```

and

```
if (d == 1)
```

using the same logic?

Comment: What, why?? Why you want to get rid of the if statements? (I think that goes under: Abuse of if statements :D)

Comment: Only to check if that's possible

Comment: Sure it's possible. But it's also ugly and unreadable. See [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/). Though those are at least artists of obfuscation.

Comment: Is your objective to make the future maintainer of this code commit suicide?

Comment: lol well there won't be any future maintainer. It's just a basic code I try to play with, to exercise myself. I guess begginer's curiosity cannot be understood by masters ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking about the motivation of this, it is a good thing if you are concerned about efficiency, as conditional branches are very time-consuming (this is the reason there are some complicated mechanisms for branch prediction). But it is not a good practice in usual code, as it might be very hard to understand for your reader, so your code becomes very hard to maintain. Also, as you are a beginner, it is a very good exercise.

Now, keep in mind that there is always a way. It is worth mentioning that you have a combination of logical, bitwise and arithmetic operation. It could be done purely with bitwise operations.

Let's try to make it using just bitwise operations. Assume your code is:

```
if (d == 0)
    e = A;
if (d == 1)
    e = B;
```

, where A and B are those 2 values you compute for e.

Firstly, extend the last significant bit to all of the d's bits (so if d is 1, it should be 0xFFFFFFFF and if it is 0, it should be 0x00000000). Then, do the operation. I splitted them into multiple lines, but it could be done more compact.

```
d = d << 1 + d;
d = d << 2 + d;
d = d << 4 + d;
d = d << 8 + d;
d = d << 16 + d;
e = (B & d) || (A & ~d);
```

Note that here I assume an int is 32 bits, which is not very portable. But, it is just an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

As you wish, no `if`-statement left:

```
!d && (
    (e = 'O'*((a+b == c) || (a+c == b) || (b+c == a))),
    (e += (e == 0)*'X'),
    printf("%c\n",e)
);

d-1 || (
    (e = 'O'*((a*b == c) || (a*c == b) || (b*c == a))),
    (e += (e == 0)*'X'),
    printf("%c\n",e)
);
```

I abused short-circuiting of `||`, `&&` and the comma-operator `,`.

Anyway, if you want to see the masters in obfuscation, look at
[The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/) .

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'm going to analyze this (never used comma-operator before!)

Comment: I'll check the obfuscation too :) Ty